# Square root of a negative number

Tags: complex-numbers

Correct me if I am wrong, $\sqrt{-4}=2i$.

But how do you explain it to a student?

We know $\sqrt{-1}=i$, but one cannot say $\sqrt{-4}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{4}=2i$ as the laws of indices can only be applied to real numbers.

Any advice would help.

Comment: Write it as $-4=(2i)^2$.

Comment: How would you answer a student if he ask why choose the positive root and not the negative?

Comment: Neither $2i$ nor $-2i$ are positive.

Comment: that is what I thought so as positive or negative does not make sense for complex numbers

Comment: so is it correct to say $\sqrt{-4}$ is the positive square root of -4?

Comment: What is $\sqrt{-4}$? Whatever it is, it is not "positive".

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

$i^2 = -1$

Therefore,

$4i^2 = -4$

and by taking square root on both sides, we have 
$2i = \sqrt{-4}$

Comment: sounds good! thanks!

Comment: How is this any different from $\sqrt{-4}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{4}$, which was rejected in the question?

Comment: Even if it isn't, why is it wrong?

Comment: One needs to be careful to know what is defined for the complex numbers. For example, $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a\sqrt b$ is not necessarily true for complex numbers.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer, is this any better?

Answer (score 1):

The square root of a negative number is usually given by
$$\begin{align}
(-4)^{1/2}
&=e^{\ln{(-4)}/2}\\
&=e^{\ln{(4e^{i\pi})}/2}\\
&=e^{\ln{(e^{i\pi+2\ln{(2)}})}/2}\\
&=e^{\ln{(2)}+i\pi/2}\\
&=2e^{i\pi/2}\\
&=2\left(\cos{\left(\frac\pi2\right)}+i\sin{\left(\frac\pi2\right)}\right)\\
&=2i\\
\end{align}$$
where the principal branch of the natural logarithm is taken instead of the 'positive' square root.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the topic dealing first with the $2 \pi$ periodicity of the angle.

Then I would pass to the convention used to split the $2 \pi$ angle: the "standard" is $-\pi < \alpha \le \pi$ thus the "principal" "standard" solution is $2i$.
But  any other split can be adopted.